# Adding a suffix at the end of each shell command

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Is it possible to automatically add some characters at the end of each command typed in the terminal.

For example, if I write

```
sudo apt-get update
```

the shell will execute

```
sudo apt-get update && notify-send Done
```

without me writing the `&& notify-send Done` part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not what you want but while waiting for a better solution you could use aliases. E.g. add the line `alias ok='notify-send Done'` to your `~.bashrc` and then write your command like this: `sudo apt-get update && ok` - That also saves some typing and you can control whether you need a notification or not.

Comment: @ByteCommander Well yeah, I'll do that until I find better solution. Thanks!

Comment: or just `&& alert`

Comment: @SylvainPineau I like to be able to customise the output, so alert doesn't work for me

Comment: It's vague to me..is the part after && (including) always going to change? Can it be empty? What about the first command ? Do you just want to type the first part or a shortcut of second part? Will the first command be changed?

Comment: @heemayl The first part will vary. The second part will always be the same. The idea is that I want the command prompt to put the second part after EVERY command i put in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `bash` as your default shell, you can set `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

From the `bash` man page:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
```

So just paste the following line in your `.bashrc` to get a notification for each command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="notify-send Done"
```

So each time your bash prompt is called (normal behavior when a command is finished, with success or not), you'll get a notification.

*Note*: you'll be also notified if you press just <kbd>Enter</kbd> as the prompt will be displayed again.

Comment: For the *after* case, `trap "notify-send Done" DEBUG` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @muru thanks for the suggestion but tested with `sleep 3`, the notification does not wait 3s.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind some characters to to an <kbd>enter</kbd> key:

```
$ bind '"\C-M":" && echo test\n"'
```

This has some drawbacks, for example if you just press Enter:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

You can block this effect by terminating your lines with <kbd>#</kbd> character - it will turn appended text into a harmless comment.

Still I'd say that this sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to play around with this, but so far I haven't found the syntax to unset it after I'm done. I was thinking there must be some placeholder like `:` which would get rid of the syntax error. Still, it begs the question as to why anyone would want to do this for *every* command. Something more focused/selective would probably be a lot more useful.

Comment: @Joe, use `bind '"\C-M":"\n"' #` to unset this. The trailing hash in the command makes the appended text a comment thus disabling its effect, just as I wrote in the answer.