# How do i efficiently use environment variables?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I'm curious about learning about choosing correct env. variables. How to make out setting what env. variable would get the job done

Example:

if you want to make sure that command history always written immediately, you can put that command into your `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable ([curiosity rose from this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145250/where-is-bashs-history-stored)):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

This is my dilemma: how was `PROMPT_COMMAND` chosen to get the job done.
How do I acquire this talent?

Comment: You want a systematic way to guess which environment variable serves your purpose?

Comment: Hard to know if you are asking about how to modify env variables, if so see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables and http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables or configure bash.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bash` as your default shell, you can indeed set `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

You usually find hints or detailed guidelines in the manual pages of a command (online from the [`bash` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bash.1.html)) or by typing `man bash` for example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
```

I did propose another solution using this env var a while ago: [Adding a suffix at the end of each shell command](https://askubuntu.com/a/646516/32239).

Ask Ubuntu is a gold mine for who wants to learn and discover more about Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `man page` of the program you are trying to influence with an environment variable. For `PROMPT_COMMAND` it's `man bash`. Since programs generally use all upper case environment variables, and environment variables are passed to programs as strings, (in the `env` array, along with the `argv` array) and accessed by name, you can generate a list including all the environment variables looked at by a program via (change `bash` to the program you're interested in):

```
strings $(type -p bash) | egrep '^[A-Z0-9]+$'
```

Or replace the `$(type -p bash)` with the actual path to the binary.

User setting of environment variables is usually done in `~/.bashrc`, or in a file called by `~/.bashrc`, like this:

```
export LESS="-XMersj3"
```

This sets my default options for `less` (See `man less`).

After a change to `~/.bashrc`, you must source the file (via `. ~/.bashrc`) to populate your environment with the updated definitions. Logging out/in also re-sources `~/.bashrc`, BUT if you've broken `~/.bashrc`, you may have trouble logging in.

Answer (score 0):

> how was PROMPT_COMMAND chosen to get the job done

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is one of the variables specific to `bash`, which runs its value as a command before printing your `$PS1` prompt on screen. By default it's unset.

> How to make out setting what env. variable would get the job done

By reading the man page of `bash`, `man bash` in terminal. There is list of environment variables there. There is no talent, only practice. And RTFM'ing, a lot.